# Kendo UI Grid .Net MVC - Column editable in Creation only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've been searching how to make a column in a Kendo Grid ASP.Net MVC (Razor) Editable only while we are in creation and not editable while in update.

Is there something special that will help me accomplish this task?

Comment: Tried with Editable, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a custom function to the onEdit event and make that column readonly:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DemoType>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
         /*...*/
      })
      .Events(events => events
          .Edit("onEdit")
      )
  )
```

Javascript:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e.model.isNew() == false) {
        //$('[name="YourcolumnName"]').attr("readonly", true);
        //replace input with span
        //taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142990/jquery-replace-inputs-with-spans
        $('[name="YourcolumnName"]').each(function() {
          $("<span />", { text: this.value}).insertAfter(this);
          $(this).hide();
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: half way correct i need it to stay like a label instead of a textbox

Comment: Thx a lot, I though there was something directly in Kendo UI Razor.

Comment: It's called programming for a reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can determine whether a row is being added or edited by just checking the id of that row.

This is how you can do it:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(p => p.id).Visible(false);
      columns.Bound(p => p.your_column).Editable("isEditable");
  })
)
```

...

```
<script>
   function isEditable(dataItem) {
      return !(dataItem.id > 0);
   }
</script>
```