# How to make a column non editable(not readonly) in edit mode and editable in create mode kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Note : 
I have checked the below post and it cannot solve my problem

[Kendo UI grid - different templates for Edit and Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321396/kendo-ui-grid-different-templates-for-edit-and-create)

I have a gird which has a dropdown column and I only need to edit this dropdown column when I create a new row template, I dont want to edit this column when a row edit function executes.

Note : The column is dropdown at the time of add new template and it will be normal text field at the time of rendering.

I have tried the below code

```
 function Onedit(e) {
        if (!e.model.isNew()) {
            var model = e.model; //reference to the model that is about the be edited

            var container = e.container; //reference to the editor container

            var categoryDropDownList = container.find("[data-role=dropdownlist]").data("kendoDropDownList"); //find widget element and then get the widget instance
            categoryDropDownList.enable(false);
        }

    }
```

But this way I can only make my drop down is read only, but still the drop down will be there. I don't need this to be happen.

What i want is when user click on edit button on the grid row it will not allow user to edit this particular column and this column value should be a string it should not looks like a read only drop down

The grid generating code is below

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModel.TemporaryItems>()
   .Name("AccessGrid")
       .Columns(columns =>
       {
           columns.Bound(p => p.Partner).Title("Partner").Width("20%").EditorTemplateName("EditorTemporaryPartnerInfo").EditorViewData(new { TemporaryPartnersList = @Model.TemporaryPartners });
           columns.Bound(p => p.UPN).Title("UPN").Width("20%");
           columns.Bound(p => p.FullName).Title("Name").Width("20%");
           columns.Bound(p => p.Access).Title("Access").Width("20%");
           columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width("10%");
       })

    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true).Height(400))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Sort(a => a.Add(b => b.FullName).Descending())
                        .PageSize(100)
                            .Model(model =>
                            {
                                model.Id(p => p.UPN);
                                model.Field(p => p.FullName).Editable(false);
                                model.Field(p => p.UPN).Editable(false);
                            })
                        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                                                    .Create(update => update.Action("Action1", "Controller1", new { id = ViewBag.PartnerKey }))
                                                    .Read(read => read.Action("Action2", "Controller1"))
                                            .Update(update => update.Action("Action3", "Controller1", new { id = ViewBag.PartnerKey }))
                        )
     .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
     .Events(e => e.Edit("Onedit"))
     .Pageable(p => p.Refresh(true).PreviousNext(false).Numeric(false))

        )
```

The filed `Partner` is a string datatype

My editor template is added below

```
@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("Type")
         .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
    .OptionLabel("---Select Partner---")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
            .BindTo(ViewBag.TemporaryPartnersList)
              .Value("1")
)
```

Comment: Change your js to replace the drop down with a span. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166226/kendo-ui-grid-net-mvc-column-editable-in-creation-only).